# Hide data if an array does not have matching value with another array on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of checkboxes with a value and table data's with the same value as an attribute and a button to compare them. What I have done is created an array when a checkbox is checked (checkedArray) and another array of table data attributes (dataArray). Then checked if checkedArray has dataArray values. On button click, if checkedArray has dataArray value then add class to the table data. In the following code, it is showing the data but not removing after I unchecked the checkbox again and compare them.

An example of my code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ksd3z0q8/).

```
var checkedArray = [];

$('.checkboxes input').on('change', function() {
  var checkedVal = $(this).val();

  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    checkedArray.push(checkedVal);
  } else {
    checkedArray.splice($.inArray(checkedVal, checkedArray), 1);
  }
});

var tabledata = $('table td');

function displayData(arr) {  
  var tableArr = $('table td').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('key');
  }).get();

  for (var i = 0; i < tableArr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (tableArr[i] === arr[j]) {
        $('table td[key="'+ arr[j] +'"]').addClass('show')
      } else {
        //$('table td:not[key="'+ arr[j] +'"]').addClass('hide')
      }
    } 
  }
}

$('#compare').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  displayData(checkedArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hide all `td` in your table before adding show class for checked ones. for that you can add `$('table tr td').removeClass('show')` before your for loop, like this:

```
function displayData(arr) {  
  var tableArr = $('table td').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('key');
  }).get();
  $('table tr td').removeClass('show');
  for (var i = 0; i < tableArr.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
          if (tableArr[i] === arr[j]) {
            $('table td[key="'+ arr[j] +'"]').addClass('show')
          } else {
            //$('table td:not[key="'+ arr[j] +'"]').addClass('hide')
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dij. This is exactly I have been looking for. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the fiddle, wouldn't you need to add 'hide' after the 1st css element? 'hide' is only called in the JS as a class but not referenced anywhere else that I'm seeing.

That is,

```
td {
  display: none;
}
```

should be

```
td.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Will do so. :)